# How do I control extra xlim/ylim space?

Tags: python, matplotlib

`matplotlib` automatically adds some small margin to plots so make them pretty:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[2,3,4])
```

the actual `xlim` is `(0.9, 3.1)` (as returned by `axes.get_xlim()`) instead of `(1,3)` dictated by the data.

This is usually reasonable except for percent plots where the limits are `(-80%,120%)` which makes for 40/140 wasted space.

How is this extra margin computed?
How can I affect it? (other than passing data max/min to `set_xlimit`).

Comment: The extra space is a margin, which can be removed with `ax.margins(0)`. See [`matplotlib.pyplot.margins`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html): *The padding added to each limit of the Axes is the margin times the data interval*

Comment: To add on to @TrentonMcKinney's answer, when using MATLAB-like plotting rather than the object-oriented approach (see the [usage guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/introductory/usage.html)), you will need to do `plt.margins(0)`.

Comment: @jared it's call the implicit "pyplot" interface, whereas "axes" is the explicit interface. https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#api-interfaces

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks for the link. I will be sure to use that verbiage in the future.